# Account for recipe changes when re-making a file

Tags: makefile, pipeline

I use Makefiles as a lightweight solution to defining Python data pipelines. Python doesn't need to be compiled, but the output data files are generated by executing Python code. I have make commands like:

```
data/out.json: data/in.json
    cat $< | python src/process_data.py > $@
```

This works nicely overall, but the problem I encounter is that when I'm actively developing `process_data.py` make keeps refusing to re-generate the file, because `out.json` is newer than `in.json`. I'd like to re-make `out.json` without complaint, however. I don't want to use `--always-make` because that also runs steps before `data/in.json` which are sometimes time-consuming.

A solution I came up with is to add the script itself to the prerequisites. By extension, it makes sense to also add the Makefile to the prerequisites. I end up with:

```
data/out.json: data/in.json src/process_date.py Makefile
    cat $< | python src/process_date.py > $@
```

1. Is this a reasonable thing to do?
2. Is it bad make style?
3. Is there a more idiomatic way of getting make to be cognizant of changes to the source files and recipes?

Comment: This is very common.  There's nothing wrong with it as long as you're aware of the ramifications (things will rebuild whenever you change anything in the makefile, even a comment etc.) and are OK with that.  There's no other way to specify dependency relationships in make, than by setting prerequisites.

Comment: Using `$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))` is perhaps better than the explicit `Makefile`